# Polymer ignore flullbleed class, but the code seems good

Tags: html, responsive-design, polymer

I'm trying to code a simple responsive website made of a `paper-header-panel` and some tabs beneath it. I've just started and guess..? Issues...

Here's the code and below it, how it should be shown and how it actually shows.

```
    <html>

    <head>

        <!-- Always load webcomponents and elements you will be using -->
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"> </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
        <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
        <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

    </head>

    <body class="fullbleed">

        <paper-header-panel class="felx">

            <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall">

                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="menuAction"></paper-icon-button>

                <div class="paper-header" id="toolbarTitle"> C. Piersigilli &#38 Associati </div>

                <span class="flex"></span>

                <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>

            </paper-toolbar>

        </paper-header-panel>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's the link to Google's Polymer website that shows the result:

[Responsive Website](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/assets/header-and-toolbar.html)

Here's what I get from the preview:

[image: Responsive Website (coded by me)]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To use the flex layout classes, you must also add this to your imports.

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
```

You've only added the non-class `iron-flex-layout` import in your code which only includes the mixins for flex-layout.

Comment: I added the string as you said but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Responsive Material Design Layouts Guide](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/responsive-material-design-layouts).

Here's the tabs example:

```
...
<head>
...
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import"
        href="/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
...
<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
  <paper-header-panel class="flex">
    <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall">
      <paper-icon-button id="navicon"
                         icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
      <!-- flex class forces span to fill space between icons -->
      <span class="flex">Title</span>
      <!-- icon displays at right because of span class above -->
      <paper-icon-button id="morebutton"
                         icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-tabs class="bottom fit" selected="0">
        <paper-tab>ONE</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>TWO</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div>Content</div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</body>
...
```

[demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/assets/drawer.html)

And the navigation drawer example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="import"
        href="/bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" 
        href="/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
...
<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
  <paper-drawer-panel class="flex">
    <paper-header-panel drawer>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div>Application</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div> Drawer content... </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
    <paper-header-panel main>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div>Title</div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div> Main content... </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>
```

[demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/assets/drawer.html)